# How to do matrix multiplication in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl, asic, iverilog

I am trying to multiply `1x3 * 3X64` matrix, here since each value in matrix is decimal number so for each value I have taken `4` bits that is `4x64` bits in total accessing `4`bits of each row at a time.

I tried to generalize it.

The matrix is of form `1x3 [2,4,3]` &

`3*64(64 decimal value in each row)`

> row 1[111111111111111111111111111111(64)]
>
> row 2[11111111(8)22222222(8).....88888888(8)]
>
> row 3[1234567812345678..................12345678]

The code which I tried

```
always@(h1,h2,h3)
        begin
z1 =((w0[3:0]*h1[3:0])+(w1[3:0]*h2[3:0])+(w2[3:0]*h3[3:0]));
z2=((w0[3:0]*h1[7:4])+(w1[3:0]*h2[7:4])+(w2[3:0]*h3[7:4]));

.
.
.
.
.   
z64=((w0[3:0]*h1[255:252])+(w1[3:0]*h2[255:252])+(w2[3:0]*h3[255:252]));


    end

        endmodule
```

I need generalized form of this..

**Error that I have got:**

> ERROR:HDLCompilers:110 - "mat.v" line 36 Least significant bit operand
>   in part-select of vector wire 'h1' is illegal

```
for(i=3;i<255;i=i+4)
        begin
            for(j=0;j<255;j=j+4)

            begin
                z[i:j]=((w0[3:0]*(h1[i:j]))+(w1[3:0]*h2[i:j])+(w2[0]*h3[i:j]));

            end
```

Answer (score 0):

A part select in Verilog must have constant bounds. `h1[i:j]` is illegal. `h1[i +: 4]` is legal and means the same as the illegal `h1[i:(i+3)]`. (And `h1[i+3 -: 4]` means the same as the illegal `h1[(i+3):i]`).

However, wouldn't your problem not be better solved by using two dimensional arrays? eg:

```
reg [3:0] h1 [0:63];
```